# Finding Probability of $p_{1,1}^{(n)}$ with Transition Matrix

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Note that this is a simplified version of a problem from a stochastic processes course.

Given transition matrix $P$, show that $p_{1,1}^{(n)} = .25 + .75(1 - 4\alpha)^n$ where

$$P = \begin{bmatrix}
1 - 3\alpha & \alpha & \alpha & \alpha\\
\alpha & 1 - 3\alpha & \alpha & \alpha\\
\alpha & \alpha & 1 - 3\alpha & \alpha\\
\alpha & \alpha & \alpha & 1 - 3\alpha
\end{bmatrix}$$

and $\alpha = [0,1/3]$. That is, the probability of changing from one state to another is $3\alpha$ and all other states have equally likely probability of being transitioned to.

---

So here is where I've gotten so far. I decided that induction is likely the best approach to solve this, and showing that $p_{1,1}^{(0)}$ is trivial, similarly
$$p_{1,1}^{(1)} = 1 - 3\alpha\\
= .25 + .75 - 3\alpha \\= .25 + .75(1 - 4\alpha)^1$$

So the trivial case is proven.

Now, assuming $$p_{1,1}^{(k)} = .25 + .75(1 - 4\alpha)^k$$
I must show that
$$p_{1,1}^{(k+1)} = .25 + .75(1 - 4\alpha)^{k+1}$$
My thought process here is that we sum the total probabilities.
$$p_{1,1}^{(k+1)} = p_{1,1}^{(k)}p_{1,1}^{(1)} + p_{1,2}^{(k)}p_{2,1}^{(1)} + p_{1,3}^{(k)}p_{3,1}^{(1)} + p_{1,4}^{(k)}p_{4,1}^{(1)}\\
=[.25 + .75(1-4\alpha)^k](1 - 3\alpha) + \alpha(p_{1,2}^{(k)}+p_{1,3}^{(k)}+p_{1,4}^{(k)})$$
But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What can you say about $p_{1,2}^{(k)}+p_{1,3}^{(k)}+p_{1,4}^{(k)}?$  Can you express it in terms of $p_{1,1}^{(k)}?$

Comment: Maybe each one is $\frac{1}{3}(1 - p_{1,1}^{(k)})$, so the total sum is $1 - p_{1,1}^{(k)}$?

Comment: Your conclusions are right, but I think the reasoning goes the other way.  The sum is $1-p_{1,1}^{(k)}$ simply because after $k$ transitions we must be in one of the states 1,2,3, or 4.  Then each states 2,3,4 has the same probability by symmetry of $P.$

Comment: Hey, that got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is thanks to the comments of saulzpatz, but by reducing $p_{1,2}^{(k)} + p_{1,3}^{(k)} + p_{1,4}^{(k)}$ to $1 - p_{1,1}^{(k)}$ by properties of a stochastic matrix, the algebra reduces quite beautifully.

$$\alpha(1 - p_{1,1}^{(k)}) + (1 - 3\alpha)p_{1,1}^{(k)}\\
=\alpha + p_{1,1}^{(k)} - 4\alpha p_{1,1}^{(k)}\\
=\alpha + p_{1,1}^{(k)}(1-4\alpha)\\
=\alpha + .25(1-4\alpha) + .75(1-4\alpha)^k(1-4\alpha)\\
=.25 + .75(1-4\alpha)^{k+1} = p_{1,1}^{k+1}$$